# SELECT some_value FROM php_array WHERE other_values (not mysql !)

Tags: php, search, multidimensional-array

In MySQL I can SELECT a value from one column of a row WHERE one or more columns have a specified value:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE birthyear = '1965' AND birthplace = 'Vancouver'
```

Now I have a multidimensional PHP_array (not a mySQL database), and I would like to extract the name from the row for a given birthyear and birthplace in a similar manner. This is the array:

```
$example = Array
(
    [0] => Array
            (
            [0] => 1965
            [1] => Bob
            [2] => Vancouver

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1973
            [1] => John
            [2] => Vancouver

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1965
            [1] => Paul
            [2] => Houston

        )

)
```

It seems to me that for each WHERE-condition I would need one loop in PHP. If you assume that I need to match several columns (birthday, birthplace, sex, occupation etc.), you'll understand how this slows down the execution over an array with thousands of entries.

How can I do this with the least number of loops?

Comment: It's just one `foreach`, not numerous loops, to look through your list.

Comment: Thank you, mario, I updated my question to reflect your comment.

Comment: If you need to compare multiple fields, try `array_intersect()` for the comparisons. Or PHPLinq for ease of use: http://phplinq.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 0):

```
array_filter($example,function($v) { return $v[0] == 1982; });
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed my question.

Answer (score 0):

This function will do what you are looking for:

```
function getNameByYear($year, array $array) {
    $name = false;
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        if ($a[0] == $year) {
            $name = $a[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    return $name;
}
```

Usage:

```
$example; // your array
$n = getNameByYear(1965, $array); // Bob
$n = getNameByYear(1973, $array); // John
$n = getNameByYear(1982, $array); // Paul
$n = getNameByYear('1965', $array); // Bob
$n = getNameByYear('1973', $array); // John
$n = getNameByYear('1982', $array); // Paul
$n = getNameByYear('wrong', $array); // false
$n = getNameByYear(2035, $array); // false
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed my question.